# Flutter listview item disappear when scrolling

Tags: listview, flutter

I put many Listile widget into my Listview, I debug the app on my physical IOS device, When i scrolled up fastly the listview, While it reached nearly the top of listview, The list item disappeared suddenly, The body area was empty,  Anyone knows how to fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

Codes:

```
    return Scrollbar(
      child:ListView.builder(
        key: const PageStorageKey("list1"),
        cacheExtent: 999999,
        itemCount: _peddingContacts.length,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
            if(index.isOdd){
              return Divider();
            }
            final idx = index ~/ 2;
            return _buildRow(_peddingContacts.elementAt(idx), 0, idx);
        })
      );
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale zh-Hans-CN)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[✓] Proxy Configuration
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: why did you put a listview inside scrollable it does not make sense cuz listview is scrollable I think removing it resolve your problem or put listview it fixed size widget

Comment: Because I want to the listview show a scroll bar. I have tried to add the fixed size widget, but  it doesn't`t work .

Comment: So i think you should add `shrinkWrap: true` in ListView.builder. ( Refer : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html).

Comment: Thanks, It`s fine after I setting the shrinkWrap.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) could redraw items previously not visible on its viewport. If the ListView items to be rendered contains a lot of Widgets, it's possible that it could cause some delay during render when scrolled fast. Here's an [informational video](https://youtu.be/LUqDNnv_dh0) from Flutter discussing how viewport works.